# Save a word document to a specific folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro to save a word document to a specific file. Here is the vba macro I have so far...

```
Sub Test1()
Dim path As String

path = "C:\Users\aroldan\OneDrive\Documents\02 - PENDING\"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=path

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

I am running this on a Word, while many tutorials show this on Excel.

Thank you!

Comment: You pass only a path, but no file name?!

Comment: If you're using Word then you'll want to reference [ActiveDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.global.activedocument) rather than `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/8224-default-save-file-name-bookmark.html, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16920-rename-document-save.html & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/37382-creating-macro-saved-word-doc-duplicates-current.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make the changes already suggested. Adding the file name to the path is enough:

```
Sub SaveAFile()
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\User\Test.docx"
    With ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs FileName:=path
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

When searching for VBA specific to Word, search on **"Word" VBA -Excel**, plus the subject keywords.

Comment: My debugger catches on the .SaveAs code line. I understand this line is to set a file name... but what does it set it to?

Comment: The sample code sets the file name to _Test.docx_. If you want help with your debugger message, please post the exact wording of the message displayed.